# php array into json and show it on ajax sucsess function

Tags: javascript, php, json

how to convert below type of array into Json in php and how to get it from ajax

```
array(4) {
  ["START_TIME"]=>
    string(19) "2017-12-19 08:34:01"
  ["END_TIME"]=>
    string(19) "2017-12-19 10:34:07"
  ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
    string(30) "MORNING TEA (AFTER BREAKFAST )"
  ["INTERVAL_ID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
}
```

here is the json i got 
[{"START_TIME":"2017-12-19 09:31:59","END_TIME":"2017-12-19 10:44:04","DESCRIPTION":"BREAKFAST","INTERVAL_ID":"1"},{"START_TIME":"2017-12-19 08:34:01","END_TIME":"2017-12-19 10:34:07","DESCRIPTION":"MORNING TEA (AFTER BREAKFAST )","INTERVAL_ID":"2"}]
how to show it on  ajax sucess funtion

Comment: Using Google you will find the function `json_encode()`. This will do exactly what you want. Next time, you should use Google first before coming here.

Comment: bro look at this  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode($arr)
```

check this [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode` to encode the array to JSON.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

The following page should help you with understanding AJAX and PHP

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp

Note that when you return a JSON object from PHP you'll have to parse it on the client side using `JSON.parse`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On Php

```
$array = [
['arr1'=>'test1'],
['arr2'=>'test2'],
]
echo json_encode($array);
```

and on Jquery ajax

```
  <script>
    $.getJSON("URL",function(response){
         console.log(response)
    })
})
</script>
```